# IllegalArgumentException: The input column cityIndex should have at least two distinct values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I'm trying to test run some ML models in databricks community edition. I've imported a csv and created a spark df and need to convert some of the strings to a compatible dtype. When using the pipeline to convert, I receive and error saying cityIndex should have at least two distinct values. How should I resolve this error. Alternatively, how would I convert my strings into a format that is compatible with the spark ML algorithms?

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import OneHotEncoderEstimator, StringIndexer, VectorAssembler

categories = ["ticket_id","city","issue_type","ticket_status","issue_description","rating","acknowledged_at","ticket_created_date_time","ticket_last_updated_date_time","address","lat","lng","location"
]
stages = []
for categoricalCol in categories:
    stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = categoricalCol, outputCol = categoricalCol + 'Index')
print(stringIndexer.getOutputCol())
encoder = OneHotEncoderEstimator(inputCols=[stringIndexer.getOutputCol()], outputCols=[categoricalCol + "classVec"])
stages += [stringIndexer, encoder]

label_stringIdx = StringIndexer(inputCol = 'issue_type', outputCol = 'label')
stages += [label_stringIdx]

assemblerInputs = [c + "classVec" for c in categories]
assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=assemblerInputs, 
outputCol="features")
stages += [assembler]

from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
df = pipelineModel.transform(df)
```

### Error Message

```
IllegalArgumentException: 'requirement failed: The input column 
cityIndex should have at least two distinct values.'
IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-3264374776080465> in <module>()
      1 from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
      2 pipeline = Pipeline(stages = stages)
----> 3 pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(df)
      4 df = pipelineModel.transform(df)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/base.py in fit(self, dataset, params)
    130                 return self.copy(params)._fit(dataset)
    131             else:
--> 132                 return self._fit(dataset)
    133         else:
    134             raise ValueError("Params must be either a param map or a list/tuple of param maps, "

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in _fit(self, dataset)
    107                     dataset = stage.transform(dataset)
    108                 else:  # must be an Estimator
--> 109                     model = stage.fit(dataset)
    110                     transformers.append(model)
    111                     if i < indexOfLastEstimator:
```

Comment: looks like city column value is same for all rows, if that is the case just don't encode it.

Comment: Thanks, that worked!